# How to install dmg files that offer no drag option

Tags: macos, install

I am trying to install SmartGit on Mac. I download their dmg file and double click on it and instead of giving me an option to drag the app to the Applications folder, it opens up a folder with the app and also related folders.

How do I install this particular application?

Answer (score 2):

Drag them all into your home folder and then run the app?

That works well if you can't find any support from the vendor. Once you have things running, you can decide to put things in /Applications or ~/Applications or elsewhere.